# What files do I need to distribute as an alternative to MS Visual C++ 2005 ATL merge modules?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, atl, winsxs

Currently I'm distributing a software product that includes three merge modules:

```
Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm
ATL.msm
policy_8_0_Microsoft_VC80_ATL_x86.msm
```

Some customers use packaging technology that doesn't like these MSM files (I think because they have technical problems with them writing to WinSxS). Can I just distribute the dll files directly into my application's Program Files folder, and if so which dlls do I need? Is it just atl80.dll?

Comment: I am not sure if this applies as a solution, but you can also build your ATL based binaries so that they are free from dependencies to redistribute ("static link"  of CRT and ATL). At the cost of having slightly heavier binaries and not sharing runtime between modules, you resolve dependency mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your alternative is to run the VC_redist.exe for that version of Visual Studio, run it from the bootstrapper with whatever setup tool you're using.

I don't know what you mean about packaging technology. The only way merge modules (msm files) can be installed is to add them at build time to an MSI file build. In other words, the only packaging technology that's relevant is Windows Installer and MSI files. So you need to find out exactly what this issue is. Everyone uses the merge modules or the VC_redist.exe because it's the only reliable thing to do.

One issue with doing it yourself in an unofficial way is that Windows Update can't find them (and that applies to static linking to). So when Microsoft applies a security fix to those Dlls then you are leaving your customers vulnerable.

Comment: They're using some weird packager that snapshots a workstation, installs our MSI, snapshots the machine, and generates a diff of the two snapshots as their install package. I don't know why.

Comment: @Rory: if you're willing to generate a separate package to meet their very strange needs, I suggest you just leave out the VC runtime altogether and tell them to get vc_redist.exe from Microsoft and install it separately.  (I don't actually see why the merge modules would cause them any problem in that scenario, but I don't suppose it matters.)

Comment: Related question: if my merge modules deliver v8.0.50727.42 but the vc_redist.exe has v8.0.50727.4053 will windows just automatically be ok with that? I don't actually know what it is in my product that's dependent on them so a bit of research is required to be sure. But in general as I understand it part of the point of these WinSxS dlls is that if windows has a more recent version it'll use that rather than complaining that the exact version isn't available, right?

Comment: In general it just works. The vc_redists tend to be later versions, and the WinSxS architecture and the policy settings redirect callers to the new versions of the Dlls.