# mergemodules .msm files are showing file elements GUID as NULL

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.7, wix3.6

I have migrated the code from Wix 2.0 and 4.0. And also migrated the Visual studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2017
Then when i was building the wix project

I was getting the below error:

light.exe(0,0) error LGHT0001: Value cannot be null

When I am investigating i found that the root cause of the issue is due to merge modules that i have used.

I have the below code related to the mergemodules in EMR_Wix_Installer_EN.wxs file.

```
<Merge Id="Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86" Language="1033" DiskId="1" SourceFile="E:\Code\EMR\Install\MSVC Dlls\Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm" />
<Merge Id="policy_8_0_Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86" Language="1033" DiskId="1" SourceFile="E:\Code\EMR\Install\MSVC Dlls\policy_8_0_Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm" />

<Feature Id="MicrosoftVCCRT" Title="Microsoft Visual Studio Redistributables" Level="1" Display="hidden">
<MergeRef Id="Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86" />
<MergeRef Id="policy_8_0_Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86"/>
</Feature>
```

And in Build.xml I have the below code

```
<property name="CRT.msm.file" location="${install}\MSVC Dlls\Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm"/>
  <property name="policy.msm.file" location="${install}\MSVC Dlls\policy_8_0_Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm"/>

<delete file="policy_8_0_Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm"/>
    <delete file="Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm"/>
```

These are the mergemodules msm packages comes with the visual studio 2005 those i kept in a shared folder and using now. But these .msm files are not there in the programfiles/commanfiles bcz now i am not using visual studio 2005.

And also i installed visual studio 2017 redistributable to get the latest .msm files

Microsoft_VC141_CRT_x86.msm

in the below path:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.14.26405\MergeModules

But I am not using the .msm files those were generated with VS2017 instead i am using the .msm those were generated with VS2005.

But with the changes when i build my wix project, compilation is working fine. But when linking light is throwing a null exception.

Below is the .wixobj file that was generated with EMR_Wix_Installer_EN.wxs

EMR_Wix_Installer_EN.wixobj

And here if we see the GUID it is showing "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" like as shown below:

```
<table name="WixMerge">
<row sourceLineNumber="E:\Code\EMR\Wix\src\EMR_WiX_Installer_EN.wxs*91"><field>Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86</field><field>1033</field><field>INSTALLDIR</field><field>E:\Code\EMR\Install\MSVC Dlls\Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm</field><field>1</field><field></field><field></field><field>{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</field></row>

<row sourceLineNumber="E:\Code\EMR\Wix\src\EMR_WiX_Installer_EN.wxs*92"><field>policy_8_0_Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86</field><field>1033</field><field>INSTALLDIR</field><field>E:\Code\EMR\Install\MSVC Dlls\policy_8_0_Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm</field><field>1</field><field></field><field></field><field>{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</field></row></table>
```

So, finally i suspected that because of this we are getting the NULL values exception "error LGHT0001: Value cannot be null"

And for time being and to test I commented the above mentioned .msm file code snippet in EMR_Wix_Installer_EN.wxs and with this the error is resolved.

Please provide your inputs and thoughts on this.

Comment: Some confusion: do you actually have the `Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm` file and the others on disk? And the path to them is correct? Try by opening the path in Orca.

Comment: I really don't think these merge modules cause your null message. I see the all-zero GUIDs in my link file as well, but it compiles correctly still. It must be some sort of implementation detail. I don't know what. Instead of the merge modules, did you consider [using the **`VC_Redist.exe`** for installing your runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27989066/129130)? Just search for "visual studio 2005 runtime".